# Magento: How to copy the Country of Manufacture Attribute into another attribute?

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I am just wondering, is there any way to copy the value of Magento's built in country_of_manufacturer which is basically list of all the countries into a new attribute?

I know this is kind of a funny question while we can just use the built in attribute. But I need to use the value into another attribute (i.e. say country_region). So how can I do that?

P.S. Please don't down vote, as I have searched a lot but couldn't find answer to this. And not sure how else I can do this either. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is to configure your new attribute to use the `catalog/product_attribute_source_countryofmanufacture` source model (See [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Countryofmanufacture::getAllOptions()` [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Source/Countryofmanufacture.php#L42). This model grabs options from the directory tables.

Ideally you would create & configure this attribute in an upgrade script for your module. You'll need necessary configuration to run upgrade scripts for your module, and then you can use this as the basis for your script:

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','default_setup');
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'your_attr_code',
    array(
        'type'      => 'varchar',
        'input'  => 'select',
        'source'    => 'catalog/product_attribute_source_countryofmanufacture',
        // other settings as desired...
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

You could also create a "dropdown" attribute in the admin, find it in the `eav_attribute` table, and edit its `source_model` column to have the listed source model. For appropriate settings, either run this sql statement...

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'country_of_manufacture';`
```

...or [look at how the `country_of_manufacture` attribute is created in the first place.](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.1-1.6.0.0.2.php#L28)

Answer (score -1):

You can set up your own extension and have a `fieldsets` declaration in the `config.xml` to copy the value from one table to another. But I don't know really how to do so in your case. Just search for "magento fieldsets"…

```
<config>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <checkout_onepage_billing>
                <username><to_customer>*</to_customer></username>
            </checkout_onepage_billing>
        </fieldsets>
        <!-- … -->
    </global>
</config>
```